# Entity Framework execute raw SQL on local data

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ef-core-2.0

For performance reasons, I want to load data from a certain table locally and execute multiple raw SQL queries on it.

My attempt so far:

```
_context.Classification.Load();
var set = _context.Classification.Local;

foreach (var condition in conditions)
{
    var query = $"select `Id` from classification where ({condition})";
    var meetsCondition = set.FromSql(query).Any();
}
```

The problem is that `set` is of type `LocalView<Classification>` and  `LocalView<T>.FromSql` does **not exist**.

Is there an alternative way of executing raw SQL on local data in Entity Framework?

**Update:** In the `conditions` list there are **raw** SQL conditions which I get from another database table. The conditions look like `DPS = 'DPSP' and HYA = 'C'` or `V in ('V1G', 'V2G')`. Therefore I have to execute a raw SQL query.

Comment: Is there a short list of the kinds of condition predicates you need to support?  There's no built-in way to write SQL over in-memory data do this, so you'll probably have to parse the condition string and evaluate it yourself.  You could, perhaps, copy the data to a local, in-memory database and use EF over _that_, perhaps SQLite.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to use an in-memory database